# Windows GCC program does not output

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, mingw, environment

I installed GCC on Windows (MSYS2) using the UCRT terminal with the following command:

```
pacman -S --needed base-devel mingw-w64-ucrt-x86_64-toolchain
```

I added `C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin` to path and I can call `g++` in Windows.

Then I compiled a simple c++ program on Windows terminal without compiling errors:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "hello world\n";
    return 0;
}
```

```
PS C:\Users\tom\source\cpp> g++ .\main.cpp
PS C:\Users\tom\source\cpp> .\a.exe
PS C:\Users\tom\source\cpp>
```

After 2 seconds, the program ends without any output.

Note that if I compile and run the same program in UCRT terminal, it will work perfectly.

This problem does not happen when I avoid using c++ language features, even if I include c++ libraries. For example, the following program does not cause this issue:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: DLL issues. Move MSYS2 to the beginning of PATH. You can also try double-clicking the .exe in the explorer to see the proper error message.